# Can anyone tell me what i need to do after testTimer. Start since Stopwatch is still underline (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, timer, stopwatch

```
private void btnTestConcatenations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var testTimer = new Stopwatch();
    testTimer.Start();
    testTimer.Stop();
    var elapsedTime = testTimer.Elapsed;

    var strTest = string.Empty;

    for (int loopcount = 0; loopcount < NUMBER_CONCATENATIONS_TO_PERFORM; loopcount++)
    {
        strTest += "Adding 20 caracters";
    }

    Application.DoEvents();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stop watch is used to time operations. Since the only other thing happening in this method is the concatenation loop, is it safe to assume that's what you want to time?

If so, you would do something like this:

```
private void btnTestConcatenations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var testTimer = new Stopwatch();
    var strTest = string.Empty;
    var numOperations = NUMBER_CONCATENATIONS_TO_PERFORM;

    // Start the stopwatch
    testTimer.Start();

    // Do some operation that you want to measure
    for (int loopcount = 0; loopcount < numOperations; loopcount++)
    {
        strTest += "Adding 20 characters";
    }

    // Stop the stopwatch
    testTimer.Stop();
    var elapsedTime = testTimer.Elapsed;

    // Do something with the stopwatch results
    MessageBox.Show($"It took {elapsedTime} seconds to do {numOperations} concatenations");
}
```